# fflib Tests fail with required fields on Account

Tags: failing-tests, fflib

I was looking to find out what approach to take with the fflib libraries and testing. I have added the fflib common and mocks files to my project and org. When I run the tests for the whole project I get a number of failures on tests in the fflib classes where an insert of an Account is done.
We have required fields on the Account and the tests fail with missing field value exception.

What approach do I take to get around this? There are a couple of thoughts I had:

1. Update the libraries to add the required field values. Not great, as it would mean having to update the libraries every time we add a new required field.
2. Remove all required fields from the UI and add the validation to the Domain class of the Account.

I have moved the fflib files to their own directory in my project.

Any help or insights as to how others deal with this issue would be really appreciated.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You should be using a Data Factory pattern. All unit tests should call the factory to create records. Adding new required fields is then as easy as updating the factory. Alternatively, you could build a generic utility that will randomly (or pseudo-randomly) generate values based on the field's metadata. Of course, this won't solve more complicated problems, like validation rules, so a factory is still the best idea.

A typical factory might go like this:

```
// We use "isTest" to ignore code coverage for this class
@isTest public class TestDataFactory {
  public static Account createAccount() {
    return new Account(
      Name='Test Account',
      Industry='Technology',
      AnnualRevenue=10000000
    );
  }
  // More methods here
}
```

Other designs include those that create and (optionally) insert records:

```
  public static Account createAccount(Boolean doInsert) {
    Account record = new Account(
      Name='Test Account',
      Industry='Technology',
      AnnualRevenue=10000000
    );
    if(doInsert) {
      insert record;
    }
    return record;
  }
```

Or perhaps they do bulk creation:

```
  public static Account[] createAccount(Integer recordCount) {
    Account[] records = new Account[0];
    Account template = new Account(
      Name='Test Account',
      Industry='Technology',
      AnnualRevenue=10000000
    );
    while(records.size() < recordCount) {
      Account temp = template.clone(false, false, false);
      temp.Name += ' ' + records.size();
      records.add(temp);
    }
    return records;
  }
```

You can also combine those, or do more complicated work, like inserting many related records, possibly in bulk, etc.

No matter how you look at it, once you have a factory, you will want to use this in all your unit tests. It's a major refactoring process, but once done, you'll have better control over your tests, allowing you to update just one class to fix many tests at once.

Answer (score 0):

The options you suggested:

1. *Update the libraries to add the required field values. Not great, as it would mean having to update the libraries every time we add a new required field.*
2. *Remove all required fields from the UI and add the validation to the Domain class of the Account.*

For option 1 - I have run into this use case and removed schema-required fields so the fflib testmethods run to completion (actually, in my use case it was violations of Shield platform encryption and I ended up submitting a PR to fflib (which was accepted)).

For option 2 - you can still have required fields on the UX but not make them schema-required and this can go a long ways towards satisfying your objective.

Otherwise, you'll need to adjust the built-in fflib testmethods in these classes (which insert Accounts)

- [fflib_SObjectSelectorTest.cls](https://github.com/apex-enterprise-patterns/fflib-apex-common/blob/83ac48bc4a043ca131530d2c0e4e3a8e13342d08/sfdx-source/apex-common/test/classes/fflib_SObjectSelectorTest.cls)
- [fflib_ApplicationTest.cls](https://github.com/apex-enterprise-patterns/fflib-apex-common/blob/83ac48bc4a043ca131530d2c0e4e3a8e13342d08/sfdx-source/apex-common/test/classes/fflib_ApplicationTest.cls?ts=4)
- possibly others

You could always do a PR against `fflib apex-common` and include smarter mocking of test accounts that used Describe to find required fields

Answer (score 0):

*Although answering this question well after the fact, hopefully someone will find this response useful.*

Generally speaking, unit tests should not execute DML, otherwise the test has to consider what's happening with a plethora of server-side, declarative logic that's likely unrelated to the Apex logic being tested -- such as required fields in this case.  I prefer that my tests focus on what my code intends, as opposed to testing Salesforce's internal functionality or unrelated declarative work.

*Side Note:  It's hard to really answer this question without knowing the context of the business logic.  In the future please consider posting a representative sample of the problematic code so that reviewers have a better understanding of the problem.*

Below is a very simple example of a service class that uses a FFLIB unit-of-work instance to save changes to Salesforce, and a unit test that precisely tests the method without need for Salesforce's underlying database.

#### DEV_AccountsServiceImpl

```java
public inherited sharing class DEV_AccountsServiceImpl
    implements DEV_IAccountsService
{
    @TestVisible
    private static Date todaysDate = Date.today();

    public void setDescription(Set<Id> accountIds)
    {
        fflib_ISObjectUnitOfWork uow = DEV_Application.UnitOfWork.newInstance();

        for (Account acct : DEV_AccountsSelector.newInstance().selectById(accountIds))
        {
            acct.Description = 'Account updated on: ' + todaysDate.format();
            uow.registerDirty(acct);
        }

        uow.commitWork();
    }
}
```

#### DEV_AccountsServiceTest

```java
@IsTest
public class DEV_AccountsServiceTest
{
    @IsTest
    static void test()
    {
        Account acct = new Account(
            Id = fflib_IDGenerator.generate(Account.SObjectType)
        );

        fflib_ApexMocks mocks = new fflib_ApexMocks();

        DEV_IAccountsSelector mockAccountsSelector = (DEV_IAccountsSelector) mocks.mock(DEV_IAccountsSelector.class);
        mocks.startStubbing();
        mocks.when(mockAccountsSelector.sObjectType()).thenReturn(Account.SObjectType);
        mocks.when(mockAccountsSelector.selectById(new Set<Id> {acct.Id})).thenReturn(new List<Account> {acct});
        mocks.stopStubbing();

        fflib_ISObjectUnitOfWork mockUoW = (fflib_ISObjectUnitOfWork) mocks.mock(fflib_ISObjectUnitOfWork.class);

        DEV_Application.Selector.setMock(mockAccountsSelector);
        DEV_Application.UnitOfWork.setMock(mockUoW);

        DEV_AccountsServiceImpl.todaysDate = Date.newInstance(2023, 3, 14);

        Test.startTest();
        DEV_AccountsService.setDescription(new Set<Id> {acct.Id});
        Test.stopTest();

        Assert.areEqual('Account updated on: ' + Date.newInstance(2023, 3, 14).format(), acct.Description);
        ((fflib_ISObjectUnitOfWork) mocks.verify(mockUoW, 1)).commitWork();
    }
}
```